# How can I separate an integer into muliple digits?

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a remainder function that finds that modulo of a number then a divider function to divide that number. My program isn't working the way I need it to. For example if I put in 2502 as my number, I should get the output of : 2 5 0 2.
I need to be able to store the value through each iteration, so for example:

```
number: 123
    123 % 10 = 3  //last digit
Number: 123 / 10 = 12
    12  % 10 = 2  //second digit
Number: 12  / 10 = 1
    1   % 10 = 1  //first digit
```

---

```
int Rem(int num);
int Div(int num);

int main() {
    int num;
    printf("Enter an integer between 1 and 32767: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    Rem(num);
    Div(num);
    printf("%d","The digits in the number are: ");

}


    int Rem(int num) {
        while(num != 0){
        int rem = num % 10;
        return rem;
        }
    }

    int Div(int num){
        while(num != 0){
        int div = num / 10;
        return div;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You return inside the loops so they only execute once and even if they ran more than once you don't change the initial value. If you want to do this in functions you need to reconsider how you're doing it. You need to preserve state between calls.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Without redoing my entire structure, what would be the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: @EdwardElric  *What structure?* You have two functions, the need for which is highly questionable from the outset. Both return some value, neither is called more than once  though the program should clearly be able to potentially produce more than one value for output . And the results of both functions are completely discarded regardless. I think [rubber-duck-debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) is more appropriate than anything else at this point. And give up looking for "efficient" right now. Shoot for *correctness* first.

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is pretty simple, but there are some subtleties. Here's some pseudo code. You'll need to convert to C.

```
num = 9934; // or get it from input
do {
    rem = num % 10;  // this gives you the lowest digit
    num = num / 10;  // divide by 10 to get rid of that lowest digit
    print rem; 
} while (num != 0);
```

I use a `do ... while` loop so the output will be correct if the user enters 0.

If you code this up and run it, you'll notice that it prints the digits in reverse order: `4 3 9 9`. So you'll need some way to reverse the digits before you output them. Three possible ways are:

1. Store the digits in an array, and then reverse the array before outputting.
2. Push each digit onto a stack. When you're done, pop each digit off the stack and output it.
3. Write a recursive function. That would eliminate the need for an explicit stack or array.

Answer (score 0):

Also you could convert it to a string and then convert back the elements of that string, but keep '\0' in mind

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this function , it return the number of digits passing by argument

```
size_t  ft_cnbr(int n)
    {
        size_t count;

        count = 1;
        if (n < 0)
        {
            count++;
            n = -n;
        }
        while (n > 9)
        {
            n = n / 10;
            count++;
        }
        return (count);
    }
```